# Why is ASP.NET MVC using the GET action parameter value for the View name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, get

Hello while working on a ASP.net MVC Website i came upon a strange problem.
While redirecting to another Action in the Controller i wanted to add a get value, which i did like this

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                return RedirectToAction("ConfirmEmailAwait", "Account", new { userId = user.Id });   //<-----[LOOK HERE]
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmailAwait?userId=d178b665-b616-4303-ae7d-00a663014109
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmailAwait(string userId)
    {
        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        // Send an email with this link
        string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = userId, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

        string emailHeader = "Confirm your account";
        string emailBody = "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";

        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userId, emailHeader, emailBody);

        return View(userId);
    }
```

As far as i can see this code does what it is supposed to do, it sends the user to the correct URL, therefore it should just work. But if you look at this image here:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JcAB.png)

The Constructed URL: http://localhost:55767/Account/ConfirmEmailAwait?userId=d178b665-b616-4303-ae7d-00a663014109

Error Message: The view 'd178b665-b616-4303-ae7d-00a663014109' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

You will see that the View it is searching for is the get value i have given it what i find very strange.

Does anyone know what is going on? am i just making a stupid mistake and not seeing it? Please help me out and thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't redirect to views. You redirect to actions.

Comment: You need to show the code for both controller methods (not links to images of it) so an answer can be added

Comment: @mason Ah thanks, i fixed it now

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing a `string` as the first parameter of `return View()` which is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String%29) where the parameter is the name of the view. You need to pass it as an `object` using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.Object%29) where the parameter is your model.

```
return View((object)userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `View(String viewName)` overload, when you want the `View(Object model)`.

To use a `String` value as a `ViewModel` you need to either cast to `Object` first...:

```
return this.View( (Object)userId );
```

...or use a parameter label:

```
return this.View( model: userId );
```

Using a parameter label is my preferred approach as the reason for casting to Object might not be immediately obvious to future readers of the code, but you might want to add a comment too so users know why the parameter was explicitly named and why it shouldn't be removed, e.g.:

```
return this.View( model: userId ); // Be careful not to call the `View(String viewName)` overload!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmailAwait(string userId)
{
    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
    // Send an email with this link
    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = userId, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

    string emailHeader = "Confirm your account";
    string emailBody = "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";

    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userId, emailHeader, emailBody);

    return View(userId);
}
```

In the above code, notice "return View(userId);"

"userId" is a string - when returning View(string), the Action thinks your userId is in fact the path to the View (the .cshtml file).

That's why the code comes up with an exception, saying it's unable to find the view matching the path supplied.

I hope that makes sense :-)